# How to Configure IntelliJ IDEA 14 for your migration from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I have recently installed IntelliJ, to learn Java. I have been learning Java previously in Eclipse, but a lot of Seniors have suggested me to start Developing in IntelliJ as it would Save time in Future.

Now the Problem is the Environment is totally different, I cannot add packages directly, i have to configure a lot of things, which is making me confuse, as to which option i need to correctly run my applications. Can anyone help me out how to go about it.

Comment: This is really too broad. We can not write down the whole documentation of IntelliJ for you. You would have to go through the documenation yourself. A good starting point would be to watch the videos given [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/) (espcecially the _Basic of working with projects_-Section and the _Project Structure and Configuration_-Section).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ is definitely different from Eclipse so a little reading on the [Getting Started](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/intellij-idea-quick-start-guide.html) pages is helpful. For me, understanding the modules part was the hardest.

For migrating from Eclipse, they have a pretty good [tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/eclipse.html) besides the IDE options to import Eclipse projects.